# How to convert number (dec) to binary (bin) number and from bin to dec?

Tags: c#

How to convert number (dec) to binary (bin) number and from bin to dec using C# and Winforms?

Comment: You mean, convert a string representation of a number from base 10 to base 2 and vice-versa?

Comment: Use the `System.Convert` namespace. And possibly `System.BitConverter`.

Comment: This lacks so much details. And WinForms isn't going to be relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
string binValue = Convert.ToString(myInt, 2);

int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(myBinary, 2);
```

Example:

```
 string binValue = Convert.ToString(16, 2); // = 10000

 int intValue = Convert.ToInt32("11010", 2);  // = 26
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s62fh68.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx